# I am getting an authenticity exception in rails 4 when I submit a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, form-for, strong-parameters, authenticity-token

Okay. I was cruising a long with a simple rails 4 app, and all of the sudden I am getting an exception, and info is not being stored in database.

Controller-

def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    if @game.save
      redirect_to @game, notice: "Game Created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

def destroy
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.destroy
    redirect_to root_path,  notice: "Game was removed."
  end

def edit
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.update(game_params)
      redirect_to @game, notice: "Game was updated"
    else
      render :edit
  end
end

private

def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:location, :date, :time)
  end
end

form -
    
    <%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>

```
  <p> <%= f.label :location %>
      <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </p>

  <p> <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.date_field :date %>
  </p>

  <p> <%= f.label :time %>
      <%= f.time_field :time, {ampm: true} %>
  </p>

  <p>
      <%= f.submit %> | <%= link_to "Cancel", @game %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is the exact exception?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/games/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=cLRLQ66BxEjbI%2Fz15EtZtiENS2RSJ9OQEY4gYUQ7OrU%3D&game%5Blocation%5D=&game%5Bdate%5D=&game%5Btime%5D=&commit=Create+Game